# VS Code - Latex Workshop - how to enable custom highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm finding the section subsection highlighting is not enough for me and I can barely see it.

I think there is a way to customize things. You can see various entries in the repo for section.name and I think you just add these to the `settings.json` but am not quite clear what to add. Is there one example in the repo that is most illustrative?

Comment: Maybe you could link these github issues. I think you can easily write those customizations in your ˋsettings.jsonˋ

Comment: The documentations of the latex-workshop says so: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Install#settings

Comment: This is probably related to your color theme, not the extension itself. But you can hack the color theme https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Comment: Got it, so it's just using the regular settings.json. Am looking at the repo but not quite clear on if there is an easy way to change the syntax highlighting settings. Just trying to make section, subsection etc big and bold.

Comment: @mathtick if you find any solution, please write it up as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I'm going to make the questions a bit more precise and I haven't quite solved it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/FAQ#customizing-a-color-theme

The scope inspector of VS Code is really helpful. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector

Answer (score 4):

Here is my color theme mimicking the Overleaf style.

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    "support.function.be.latex",
                    "support.function.general.tex",
                    "support.function.section.latex",
                    "support.function.textit.latex",
                    "support.function.texttt.latex",
                    "support.function.textbf.latex",
                    "support.function.textsc.latex",
                    "support.function.url.latex",
                    "support.function.footnote.latex",
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#0000FF"
                }
                
            },
            {
                "scope": [
                    "variable.parameter.function.latex",
                    "constant.other.reference.citation.latex"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#67a4ad",

                }
            }
        ],

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the style configurations that I use in my projects.

[GitHub gist - style configs for LaTeXWorkshop](https://gist.github.com/CloudyPadmal/5944148644d66786998b8583030453e8)

Add this json block to `settings.json` from `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`

[image: preview]

May be it's too colourful... Please feel free to edit the json to fit your needs.

You can try to find the "scope"s using `Preferences: Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`. More on scopes at the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start for overleaf dark mode, based on the answer by Yiwei Jiang above:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "support.function.be.latex",
                "support.function.general.tex",
                "support.function.section.latex",
                "support.function.textit.latex",
                "support.function.texttt.latex",
                "support.function.textbf.latex",
                "support.function.textsc.latex",
                "support.function.url.latex",
                "support.function.footnote.latex"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#52ABE3"
            }
            
        },
        {
            "scope": [         
                "keyword.control.cite.latex",
                "keyword.control.label.latex"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF79AA"
            }
            
        },
        {
            "scope": [
                "variable.parameter.function.latex",
                "constant.other.reference.citation.latex"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FFAB50",

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How does "highlighting" become " dark mode" ? Seems like this "answer" does not actually answer the proposed question.

Comment: Okay, more correctly:
Highlighting, mimicking the dark theme of Overleaf.

Thought it might help those coming from Overleaf, as it did for me.

Wanted to place it as answer to the other highlighting suggestion, bust since I made this account just to add this comment, I was not yet allowed to directly answer.